# mysql many to many inner join with and condition

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

I have 3 tables, posts , tags and post_tags. posts and tags have many to many relationship.

```
posts table
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | title                                                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | title1                                               |
|  2 | title2                                               |
|  3 | title3                                               |
+----+------------------------------------------------------+

post_tags table
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | tag_id |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1 |       1 |      2  |
| 2 |       1 |      3  |
| 3 |       1 |      4  |
| 4 |       2 |      2  |
| 5 |       2 |      4  |
| 6 |       2 |      5  |
| 7 |       2 |      6  |
| 8 |       3 |      3  |
| 9 |       3 |      4  |
| 10 |      3 |      5  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

So, I need to find the posts based on the tag_id, in case if I have only one tag the solution seems easy.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN post_tags
ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id 
    AND post_tags.tag_id = 2
```

so, I get only those posts that have tag_id 2 in post_tags table. So, now I want to fetch only those posts, that have tag_id 2 and 3 at the same time. I mean, if some posts have tag_id 2 but not 3, these should NOT be fetched. How can I achieve that?

I tried this

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN post_tags
ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id
    AND post_tags.tag_id = 2 
    AND post_tags.tag_id = 3
```

But it returns empty, and I guess I can understand why, as it seems that make two and conditions for the same tag_id field.

**UPDATE:**

this query returns all posts that have tag_id 2 OR 3, but and need 2 AND 3

```
    SELECT posts.id, posts.title 
    FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN post_tags 
    ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id AND post_tags.tag_id IN (2,3);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you pls show your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT p.id, p.title 
  FROM post p JOIN post_tags t
    ON p.id = t.post_id
 WHERE t.tag_id IN (2, 3)
 GROUP BY p.id, p.title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag_id) = 2
```

Output:

```
| ID |  TITLE |
---------------
|  1 | title1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c74fcb/4)** demo

Comment: it works !!, thanks for the reply, I just wanted to ask one thing, is this the most optimized way (if there are any other ways), cause I am dealing with large dbs. Thanks

Comment: @Davo It should be fast enough. Make sure that you have all necessary indices. And as always with performance optimization do `EXPLAIN` on the query and benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this could help to do the trick

```
select posts.id, posts.title 
from posts
INNER JOIN post_tags
ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id 
group by posts.id
having max(post_tags.tag_id=2) > 0 
and    max(post_tags.tag_id=3) > 0
```

You can check the solution [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c74fcb/9)

Comment: Thanks this did the job for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use IN clause

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title FROM posts INNER JOIN post_tags ON posts.id = post_tags.post_id AND post_tags.tag_id IN (2,3);
```

may this works for you

Comment: thanks for the response, but this returns all the posts that have tag_id 2 or 3

Comment: try adding "group by post_tags.post_id" in the above query